# Is it possible to access a JSON file using Javascript without using a JSON server?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON file in the same folder as my Javascript file. I have been looking for a way to simply access the JSON file and parse through it using Javascript. I thought it would be as simple as just referencing it and parsing it, however the only solutions i have found seem to be either parsing JSON that is natively stored within a Javascript file, or having to fetch a JSON file off of a server using AJAX. Surely there has to be an easy way to just reference it and open it using Javascript, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript cannot access the files that are stored on server. If it could, it would cause massive security issues.

Solution 1:

- That's what you do with the server-side language(e.g PHP) and then parse it to JS (for 
  example using json.encode() in PHP)

Solution 2:

- Using AJAX call

Solution 3:

- Try using it directly in same JS file or another JS and then import it

Comment: I see, that makes sense to me. I think for my needs the AJAX method will work best. Thank you for clarifying that for me!